# can I adjust if the text reaches the certain number of characters go to the next line? (Html/css/php)

Tags: php, html, css, text

how can I adjust if the text reaches the ceiling or at least a certain number of characters go to the next line?
I mean I have a `div` but my text(I get it from mysql) is a little longer than my page and a scrollbar will show but I want the text to go to the next line

I tested this code :

```
<div class="info">
<?php
$strec = $row["text"];
if (strlen($row["text"]) >= 980) {
   $strec = str_replace(" ", "\n", $row["text"]);
}
?>
<p><?=$strec?></p>
</div>
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Instead of "\n" use "<br>". Is there any reason not to use a CSS style like `max-width` and or `width` on `.info`?

Comment: I used max-width but text didn't go to the next line. It just converted to "examp..." (for example text is example of my code"

Comment: Sorry I'm lost then. There must be something else going on that is not apparent in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look for something like `white-space: nowrap` in your css and if you find it, remove it (maybe it is in your div)

Comment: Oh it fixed i changed that to `white-space: normal` thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with character units (ch) in CSS!

try this out

```css
p {
  max-width: 10ch
}
```

```html
<p>i am way bigger than 10 characters long dont you think?</p>
```

Comment: Actually I tested this but but text didn't go to the next line. It just converted to "examp..." (for example text is example of my code"

Comment: Interesting, could I see the rest of your CSS and HTML @TheGloriesVe? Perhaps you have some ellipsis css written somewhere thats making that the end result. Sorry for the late response too, been a busy day.

Comment: It's a lot of css codes i think i can't put all of those in here. Can i send it in pv? It's ok thank you for helping me

Comment: yeah sure! whatever works, github repo, a codepen, whatever is more convenient for you for me to have a look.